# Remove private shared libraries from Depends field in control

Tags: package-management, shared-library, debian-installer, dh-make

I'm using command `debuild -b` to package my application into a .deb. When it goes to run `dh_makeshlibs`, many shared libraries' names are added in debian/my-package/DEBIAN/shlibs. But some of them are my private shared libraries, which will be packaged into .deb, too. In the generated control file, these shared libraries are listed in Depends field. It caused the error when install .deb on other machine because these shared libraries are not intalled yet.

My question is how to remove the private shared libraries from Depends field, but just leave some public shared libraries?

Here is debian/install:

> my-package/* opt/my-package
>
> private_lib/* usr/lib/my-package # I used -rpath to tell linker where to find my private libraries

I'm learning how to package, so might be unclear on somewhere. Please tell me if you need more infomation that will help.